# Activating a minor mode for outline-minor-mode for elisp files

Tags: minor-mode

I am working on a minor mode that adds functionality to `outline-minor-mode` associated with different major modes (e.g. `emacs-lisp-mode`, `fortran-mode`).

This is the minor mode file `taxocalc.el`

```
;; taxocask.el
(require 'taxocask-elisp)

(defun taxocask-activate ()
   "Activates the minor mode" 
   (do-this))

(defun taxocask-deactivate ()
   "Reverts to default outline settings." 
   (do-that))

(define-minor-mode taxocask-minor-mode
  "Enhances visibility of heading levels and text emphasis."
  :init-value nil
  :lighter " Taxocask"

  (if taxocask-minor-mode
      (taxocask-activate)

    ;; [ELSE] Rvert the functionality provided by minor mode
    (taxocask-deactivate)) )

;;;###autoload
(defun taxocask-enable ()
  "Enables `taxocask-minor-mode'."
  (taxocask-minor-mode 1))

;;;###autoload
(defun taxocask-disable ()
  "Disables `taxocask-minor-mode'."
  (taxocask-minor-mode 0))

(provide 'taxocask)
```

This is the contents of `taxocalc-elisp.el`.

```
;; taxocalc-elisp.el

(defun taxocask-elisp-view ()
  "Viewing emacs-lisp outline structures."
  (define-key emacs-lisp-mode-map (kbd "H-o s") #'outline-show-subtree)
  (define-key emacs-lisp-mode-map (kbd "H-o i") #'outline-show-children)
  (define-key emacs-lisp-mode-map (kbd "H-o k") #'outline-show-branches)
  (define-key emacs-lisp-mode-map (kbd "H-o e") #'outline-show-entry) )

(provide 'taxocask-elisp)
```

I am struggling to see how the mode be activated for elisp files.  I want to allow the user to enable `outline-miner-mode` in an emacs lisp file (`.el`), at which point
`taxocask-elisp` is also activated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would `(add-hook 'emacs-lisp-mode-hook FUNC)` and in that FUNC function you would `(add-hook 'outline-minor-mode-hook 'taxocask-minor-mode nil t)`

That non-nil LOCAL argument means you're only doing something with `outline-minor-mode-hook` in the current buffer.

---

Edit: Assuming you actually want to *toggle* your mode on and off in alignment with `outline-minor-mode-hook` you'll want that hook function to be something which tests `outline-minor-mode`.

Like this:

```el
(add-hook 'emacs-lisp-mode-hook 'foo--enable)

(defun foo--enable ()
  "Enable tracking of `outline-minor-mode' in current buffer."
  (add-hook 'outline-minor-mode-hook 'foo--toggle-with-outline-minor-mode
            nil :local))

(defun foo--toggle-with-outline-minor-mode ()
  "Toggle `foo-mode' with `outline-minor-mode' buffer-locally."
  (foo-mode (if outline-minor-mode 1 0)))

(define-minor-mode foo-mode
  "Foo mode."
  :init-value nil
  (if foo-mode
      (message "Foo enabled.")
    (message "Foo disabled.")))
```

Comment: Meaning the use of `(add-hook 'emacs-lisp-mode-hook #'taxocask-elisp-view)` in `taxocask.el` ?   And in  `taxocask-elisp-view` add `(add-hook 'outline-minor-mode-hook 'taxocask-minor-mode nil t)` ?

Comment: I also need a call to `(taxocask-activate)`.  How should this be ?

Comment: I am unsure what to do to make the minor mode word. I have put a call to `(taxocask-activate)` which is designed to activate the minor mode capability but do not know what to put in it. Your generic suggestion `(add-hook 'emacs-lisp-mode-hook FUNC)` is not specific enough for me to understand exactly what to do and to what `FUNC` actually refers to.

Comment: I've added a generic example.

Comment: Much appreciated.  Would I need to call anything specific in the condition `(if foo-mode` ?  Or is the hook for the function `'foo--enable` enough to activate `foo-minor-mode` whenever an elisp file is loaded ?

Comment: `(if foo-mode` is just testing whether `foo-mode` is in the process of being enabled or disabled, in the same way that `(if outline-minor-mode 1 0)` is testing whether `outline-minor-mode` is in the process of being enabled or disabled.  Both modes are minor modes and so can be enabled *or* disabled, and so the mode bodies and any mode hook functions should generally check the mode variable to see which of those two things is happening.  I recommend that you just experiment with this code; I think any questions you have can be answered simply by trying it.