# How to automatically turn on one minor mode when another is turned on?

Tags: minor-mode

I have a minor mode called `tematika-minor-mode`.  When I turn it on, I want to enable `outline-minor-mode` automatically.  And turn it off when `tematika-minor-mode` is disabled.

Comment: Your question seems to be what I rewrote the title to be. If so, get rid of all of your code and just ask the question. Or if that's not your question, and you have a *specific* question about some *part* of your code, then show that part and ask that specific question. And if you have both questions then post them separately. Thx.

Comment: Yes, it is about the title you wrote.

Comment: Then please remove all of the rest that is extraneous. If you have some specific question about some code, post that as a separate question. Thx.

Comment: Your own question [Activating a minor mode for outline-minor-mode for elisp files](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/77494/activating-a-minor-mode-for-outline-minor-mode-for-elisp-files) encapsulates this question.  In the Answer, `foo-mode` and `outline-minor-mode` are both minor modes, and one mode is made to track the other in the exact way you're asking for here.  (The difference between that question and this is only the interaction with `emacs-lisp-mode` which you don't need here.)

Comment: Looking at your edit history for this new question, it started out with a modified and buggy adaptation of the code from the earlier Answer, so I suggest that you review that Answer and your custom code together and make sure you have that part correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming that `tematika-minor-mode` is a buffer-local minor mode, not a global minor mode.

Adapting my answer from your earlier related question: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/77495/454 you can do the following.  The difference is that this time we're adding to the *global* value of the minor mode hook (because you don't care what kind of buffer the minor mode is being enabled in), whereas in the earlier question we were restricting the cases where we triggered the behaviour by using the *buffer-local* value of the minor mode hook (because you only wanted it if the minor mode was enabled in an elisp buffer).

```el
(add-hook 'tematika-minor-mode-hook 'my-outline-toggle-with-tematika-minor-mode)

(defun my-outline-toggle-with-tematika-minor-mode ()
  "Toggle `outline-minor-mode' with `tematika-minor-mode' buffer-locally."
  (outline-minor-mode (if tematika-minor-mode 1 0)))
```

Or if `tematika-minor-mode` is your own custom code, you could simply update the mode definition:

```el
(define-minor-mode tematika-minor-mode
  ...
  (if tematika-minor-mode
      (progn
        ...
        (outline-minor-mode 1))
    ...
    (outline-minor-mode 0)))
```

Comment: T like the second version as it avoids the hook.  I find using hooks somewhat complicated.

Comment: If you're writing custom code for your own use and you don't *need* to use a hook, then there's probably very little reason to consider doing so.  Hooks are extremely useful, but for the most part they are for interacting with code written by *other* people.